# what dose "char const * name() const _WEBSOCKETPP_NOEXCEPT_TOKEN_ {" mean

Tags: c++, socket.io

Iv been banging my head against the wall for a while now trying to sort this error  out but i do not understand what what the code is doing.

This is the code i am stuck on. what is it saying ? a function that returns a pointer. what dose "const _WEBSOCKETPP_NOEXCEPT_TOKEN_" mean ? it it some sort of define if so why is it here ?

```
char const * name() const _WEBSOCKETPP_NOEXCEPT_TOKEN_ {
    return "websocketpp";
}
```

here is the error code im getting in VS

[pic of vs errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HlFl.png)

```
    ● Started at 18:51:08
    1>------ Build started: Project: boost_thread_test, Configuration: Debug 
    x64 ------
    1>boost_thread_test.cpp
    1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\error.hpp(226): error C2259: 'websocketpp::error::category': cannot instantiate abstract class
    1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client

-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\error.hpp(226): note: due to following members:
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\error.hpp(226): note: 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const': is abstract
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\frame.hpp(831): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\processors\base.hpp(165): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::processor::error::processor_category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\processors\base.hpp(165): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::processor::error::processor_category::name'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\base\connection.hpp(187): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\base\connection.hpp(187): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::error::category::name'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\common\md5.hpp(367): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'websocketpp::md5::md5_word_t', possible loss of data
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\sha1\sha1.hpp(176): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\iostream\base.hpp(77): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::iostream::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\iostream\base.hpp(77): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::iostream::error::category::name'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\extensions\extension.hpp(65): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::extensions::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\extensions\extension.hpp(65): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::extensions::error::category::name'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\asio\base.hpp(205): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::asio::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\asio\base.hpp(205): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::asio::error::category::name'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\asio\security\base.hpp(107): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::asio::socket::socket_category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>c:\librarys\socket.io-client-cpp-master\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\transport\asio\security\base.hpp(107): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::asio::socket::socket_category::name'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\system_error(83): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>Done building project "boost_thread_test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
● Finished at 18:51:12 (total time 4.27s)
```

Comment: Please add the body of the error you're getting to your question as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/websocketpp/common/cpp11.hpp
Looks like it's mostly a sinonym for [`noexcept`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956976.aspx).

This basically means that the function is expected to not throw any exceptions.

The function returns a const pointer to const char. This means that you can't change the pointer, nor can you change what it points to.

Comment: oh...ok do you know what i need to do to clear my errors ? cheers

Comment: Don't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: thanks you i have changed that now. but im still getting the other errors that i do not understand. do you know what could cause it ?